# LowPower.clockMode(CLOCK_MODE_32MHz)での「Software Serial ライブラリ」動作

Tags: spresense, arduino

SPRESENSE Arduino IDE（Ver1.8.16）で、「Software Serial ライブラリ」を使用したプログラム作成をしています。

LowPower.clockMode(CLOCK_MODE_32MHz)を設定し、動作クロックを32MHzに落とすと正常に通信できなくなります。
この設定を外してクロックモードの指定なしにすると正常に通信できています。
スピードは115200bpsです。

Spresenseの「Software Serial ライブラリ」はクロックモード設定に対して何か制限があるのでしょうか？
Webの開発者情報では特に記述が見つかりませんでした。
電池動作のシステムを開発しており、CLOCK_MODE_32MHzで動作させてできるだけ電力消費量を落とそうとしています。
アドバイスいただけると助かります。
（以下12/17 追加）
各モード設定時のTx波形をオシロスコープで測定してみました。
結果、CLOCK_MODE_32MHzにすると送信パルスが115200bpsからずれてしまっています。
（１）クロックモード・通常時
[image: 正常動作]
（２）クロックモード設定：CLOCK_MODE_32MHz
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
このクロックのズレが正常に通信できない原因と思われます。
ライブラリーの不具合ではないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

`SoftwareSerial`ライブラリの中身を覗いてみると、`bitDelay`で時間を調整しているようです。CPUクロックでディレイを調整しているので、CLOCK_MODE_32MHzでCPUクロックを下げた場合には対応されていないのかもしれません。

https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense-arduino-compatible/blob/master/Arduino15/packages/SPRESENSE/hardware/spresense/1.0.0/libraries/SoftwareSerial/SoftwareSerial.cpp#L238

```cpp
void SoftwareSerial::begin(long speed)
{
  unsigned long bitDelay;

  pinMode(_transmitPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(_receivePin, INPUT_PULLUP);

  /* 4-cycle delays (must never be 0!) */
  bitDelay = (clockCyclesPerMicrosecond() * 250000) / speed;
  _tx_delay = bitDelay - 16;
  _rx_delay_centering = bitDelay + (bitDelay / 2) > 160 ? bitDelay + (bitDelay / 2) - 160 : 1;
  _rx_delay_intrabit = bitDelay - 16;
```

ただ、オシロスコープで波形をみながら自分で`bitDelay`を調整すれば、CLOCK_MODE_32MHzでも動作するのではないかと思います。是非試してみてください。

Comment: 早速に回答いただきありがとうございました。
さすがにメーカー製の保証されたライブラリーを改版して対応するのはやりたくありません。

現状、このSoftwareSerialを使用した通信を行うときだけ、クロックモードを通常（156M）に戻し、通信が終わったら32Mに戻して対応しています。
この場合、クロックモード変更後に「xxx.Serial.begin(115200);」を実行する必要がありますが。

一応これでうまく動作していますが、少しでも消費電力を抑えるためにはあまりやりたくない方法です。

ここはメーカーさんのサポートの方も見ていると思いますが、正式な見解をいただけると助かります。